# Varying Search Result Pages

Tags: themes, loop, search, forms

I have two different kinds of search results on my site and I'd like to change the look of the search result page entirely. I've played around with the search form a bit but I'm unsure how to force it to redirect to an alternate search.php Any help would be appreciated

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchsupport" action="/">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search')  
    {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '')  
    {this.value = 'search';}" id="s" name="s" value="search" class="search-form round"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit"> 
    <input type='hidden' name='post_type' value='software, documents' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add an hidden filed to your search form and include a different template based on that:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchsupport" action="/">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search')  
    {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '')  
    {this.value = 'search';}" id="s" name="s" value="search" class="search-form round"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit"> 

    <!-- this is the magic field --->
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_search" value="1"> 

    <input type='hidden' name='post_type' value='software, documents' />
</form>
```

then in your theme's search.php at the very top add:

```
if (isset($_GET['custom_search']) && $_GET['custom_search'] == 1){
   include('custom_search.php'); // change it to whatever template file you would like to use
   break;
}
```